# Python WordNet Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to remove any word from a dataframe that is not in the nltk corpus, wordnet

```
dFrame['newtext'] = [' '.join([(i) for i in x.split()]) for x in dFrame['newtext'] if wn.synsets(i) == True]
```

I am checking each word to see if it exists in the corpus, and if it does then I want to keep it

I am getting an unresolved reference on the i in wn.synsets(i)

any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
dFrame['newtext'] = dFrame['newtext'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([i for i in x.split(' ') if wn.synsets(i)]))
```

If you prefer your approach, then change it into this:

```
dFrame['newtext'] = [' '.join([(i) for i in x.split() if wn.synsets(i)]) for x in dFrame['newtext']]
```